# How to get text from a paragraph without including text from some child element Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>The table predicted, with </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="RKH RKH" w:date="2016-11-06T17:53:00Z" w:id="0">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>impressive</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="RKH RKH" w:date="2016-11-06T17:53:00Z" w:id="1">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="001F31B2" w:rsidRPr="001F31B2">
            <w:delText>stunning</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
 </w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>The man started </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:author="RKH RKH" w:date="2016-11-06T17:53:00Z" w:id="0">
        <w:r>
            <w:t>to run.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:del w:author="RKH RKH" w:date="2016-11-06T17:53:00Z" w:id="1">
        <w:r w:rsidDel="001F31B2" w:rsidRPr="001F31B2">
            <w:delText>to hike.</w:delText>
        </w:r>
    </w:del>
 </w:p>
```

I get the paragraphs as follows and loop through them.

```ruby
@all_paragraph_nodes = @file.xpath('//w:p')

@all_paragraph_nodes.each_with_index do |p, index|
...
```

I want to get the text from each paragraph in the loop excluding the text inside of the  `<w:del>` element.

How can I do this using Nokogiri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all child elements of the `w:p`, and then use a predicate with [`not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-not) and [`name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) to filter out the `w:del` elements.

```ruby
@all_paragraph_nodes.each_with_index do |p, index|
  text_nodes = p.xpath("*[not(name(.)='w:del')]//text()")
  # ... process however you want
end
```

You will probably need to remove the empty text nodes. You could do this in Ruby, or you could filter them out in XPath with [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)

```ruby
p.xpath("*[not(name(.)='w:del')]//text()[normalize-space()]")
```

Comment: Thank you matt. Works perfectly. Where did you learn to work with nokogiri? I can't seem to find very many good tutorials for noobs.